# How postman can send customer headers in websocket

Tags: websocket, postman, request-headers

I'm trying  to implement oauth with websocket
In backend i use go
and in frontend i use websocket built in of browser

I want to sent header Authorization bearer along with websocket request.
So far i had research and notice that websocket not allow to add header

But in postman websocket request i see its can attach header along with its

Here is the picture

[image]

How can postman do this?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but no i also want to know how postman can post header along  with its

Comment: To my knowledge, you cannot pass extra headers with the native browser Websocket object (you can do it however server side using https://github.com/websockets/ws).

I wonder if that is what they are doing on Postman?

Comment: how the hell this question get marked as duplicated ???????
the link for the duplicated question is for js
mine is for postman ?
WTH is this filter